# Trouble understanding ?:, ?=, ?!, and backreferences . . 

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning about regular expressions for a script I will be writing down the road, but I've hit a stopping point. I basically understand what `?=` and `?!` do, they're "lookaheads". To borrow and example: `/Win (?=98)/` only matches "Win " if it is followed by "98" whereas `/Win (?!XP)/` would match "Win " only if it **was not** followed by "XP" . . . right?

Now I really don't get the `?:` delimiter. And I haven't found a decent example of it and I'm just really, really confused about it. :/ I understand it's supposed to match the entire contained pattern or something?

One more thing I'm confused about are backreferences. Here's on example I found: the regular expression `/<(\S+).*>(.*)<\/\1>/` is supposed to match "any tag". I'm just confused as to what the number "1" refers the browser to . . . is it the first match - in which case I would think it would refer to the `<` character - or something else?

I'm just now dabbling into the world of regular expressions and would love some clarification on these concepts, thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thoughts on the lookahead assertions are correct.

`\1` refers to the first submatch in parentheses, i.e. whatever was matched by the `(\S+)` in your example. `\2` refers to the second (in the example, `(.*)`) and so on.

`?:`, on the other hand, means that that set of parentheses should not be tied to a reference like `\1`. You use it if you need parenthesis for something but don't really care about getting the matched text later on. So, in the regular expression `/(?:abc)def(ghi)/`, `\1` would not expand to `abc` (because we switched that off using the `?:`), but to `ghi`.

Comment: Kruger So what you're saying is that the backreferences `\1` and `\2` will only apply to matches created in parentheses? Is that what "capturing" is? When a match is made in parentheses? Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

> Now I really don't get the ?: delimiter. And I haven't found a decent example of it and I'm just really, really confused about it. :/ I understand it's supposed to match the entire contained pattern or something?

The ?: operator allows you to group parts of a regex (just like bare parentheses do), *without* capturing them. In fact, it's basically called a "non-capturing group".

So for example:

```
/^(.*?)(foo|bar)(.*?)$/
```

Result: First capturing group contains the text before the match, second contains either "foo" or "bar", third contains the rest.

```
/^(.*?)(?:foo|bar)(.*?)$/
```

Result: First capturing group contains the text before the match, second contains the text after.

Comment: Ok, I've read tutorials about regexes that talk about "matching" and "capturing", but I just now realized that I don't know what they mean. Until now I thought that they were interchangeable but apparently not . . .